# How to disable auto menu showing on fullscreen on Yosemite?

Tags: menu-bar, fullscreen

So when using full screen on any app is there a way to disable the top menu from auto showing when you hover over it? It's pretty annoying because when it pops open it shifts down the entire screen.

I have a 2014 MacBook Air running Yosemite.

Edit:
So far it looks like that's just a built in feature of Yosemite (maybe previous flavors too). I guess you just have to train yourself to not go that far up when you are in full screen mode.

As an aside, I learned that when the dock is hidden in full screen mode it works in a funny way. If you want the dock to show, you have to move the cursor on it while still having your finger on the trackpad. If you just move the cursor to the dock location and immediately remove your finger, the dock will not show. This is actually a pretty good design because when you want the dock to actually pop up you tend to keep your finger on the trackpad. If it's just an accidental swipe that happens to land the cursor over the dock location, this probably means you didn't intend that movement!

Comment: it's a shame to have to train yourself to avoid a problem that is very definitely a user experience design flaw